# Is there any security issue in using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render HTML Code inside our React.js sharepoint modern web-part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, security, react

I am trying to build a React JS SharePoint modern web part, which have the following capabilities:

1. Inside the Web Part settings page >> there are 2 fields named as "Who We Are" & "Our Value" which allow the user to enter HTML.
2. The web part will render 2 buttons "Who We Are" & "Our Value" >> and when the user clicks on any button >> a Popup will be shown with the entered HTML code in step-1.

Something as follow:

[image]

But to be able to render HTML code as Rich-Text inside my Web Part, I have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute inside the `.tsx` file, as follow:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal2 = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}>
   </p>

        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

so my question is: if using

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}></p>
```

can poses any security issues to render HTML Code inside react.js SharePoint web part?

and if so can I eliminate this security issue? if not, then can I use a safer approach to render HTML code as Rich-Text inside a Popup?

Here is my Full web part code:

inside the `MyModalPopupWebPart.ts`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are",
    multiline: true
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value"
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description",
    multiline: true
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

inside the `MyModalPopup.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml),

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

So, in general there are security issues related cross site scripting (XSS) using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. But, in your case, I believe you or site admin will be entering HTML in property pane settings & as long as you enter clean HTML there should not be any issues using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Also, I see lot of community members are using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in their solutions/samples: [sp-dev-fx-webparts samples search](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/search?q=dangerouslySetInnerHTML).

---

Also, if XSS is your primary concern, you can use Sanitizer libraries to sanitize your HTML before inserting it in the DOM via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

You can find more information about this at:

1. [Safe alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
2. [How to prevent XSS attacks when using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React](https://dev.to/jam3/how-to-prevent-xss-attacks-when-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-react-1464)

Comment: welcome back :) .. now you mentioned `But, in your case, I believe you or site admin will be entering HTML in property pane settings & as long as you enter clean HTML there should not be any issues using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.`.. but in my case any user will be able to use the web part inside the modern pages.. i do not think we can lock down the web part to be added by the site admin only.. also if many users are using this inside their solution/samples this does not mean it is safe.. am i correct?

Comment: 1. Only users with *Contribute/Edit* & higher permissions will be able to edit the page > add & configure web part. Limited set of users/content authors should have these permissions & other users should be visitors (read access).
2. I am not saying that this is 100% safe because others are using it >> I just pointed it as it is related to your case (we are also using it in multiple enterprise level web parts without any issues so far) >> Also, I have suggested the solution to sanitize your HTML before adding to DOM if you don't feel it is safe for your environment.

Comment: in our case all user can write modern pages so they can add the web part i am currently developing... .. also can you specify how i can sanitize the HTML to be used inside the web part in a safer way?

Comment: Check last two links in my answer. There are some libraries which you can use to sanitize the HMTL content. Examples are included in reference links.

Comment: so what i did >> i install this inside my project `npm install dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss` >> then i added the following import to my `MyModal.tsx` `import { sanitize } from 'dompurify';` >> then i render the HTML using this code `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(myprops.WhoWeAre) }} />` .. so i am safe now?